# getPreferenceScreen()

Tags: android

I need check a value and enable or disable programatically "checkboxpreference". I using this code but getPreferenceScreen() wants a method and I don't know which method use. (I use this on android 2.1).

```
                        <CheckBoxPreference
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:title="Now"
                        android:defaultValue="false"
                        android:key="keep" />



protected void check(){

        // read values

        if (values){
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("checkbox-preference-key").setEnabled(true);
        }
        else {
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("checkbox-preference-key").setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getPreferenceManager()` instead.

So your code now looks like:

```
getPreferenceManager().findPreference("keep").setEnabled(values);
```

This is the equivalent of

```
if (values){
  getPreferenceManager().findPreference("keep").setEnabled(true);
}
else {
  getPreferenceManager().findPreference("keep").setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: The method getPreferenceManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: Why are you not using a PreferenceActivity?

Comment: I should ask to myself! :-) Is there any difference if I use this code in MainActivity?

Comment: @PolHallen since MainActivity seems to only be extending `Activity` you don't have the methods `getPreferenceScreen()` and `getPreferenceManager()` whereas a `PreferenceActivity` does. I recommend moving all your preference stuff inside a `PreferenceActivity`. [This](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/preferenceactivity-basics) tutorial can give a bit more info.

Comment: isn't getPreferenceManager itself deprecated as well?

Comment: @Maysam it wasn't about deprecation. Neither `getPreferenceManager()` nor `getPreferenceScreen()` are deprecated on Android 2.1. When I first read the question, I understood the problem as not using the `getPreferenceScreen()` method properly, so I suggested `getPreferenceManager()`.

Comment: you're right, I was googling for deprecation resolutions and didn't pay attention to that this question has nothing to do with deprecation