# Why the "The method getPreferenceOnScreen is depriciated" is shown?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am developing a simple android app. I have set preferences through a method which is given below-

```
public void updateSummaries() {
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_SIP_DOMAIN).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_SIP_DOMAIN, DEFAULT_SIP_DOMAIN));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_SIP_PROXY).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_SIP_PROXY, DEFAULT_SIP_PROXY));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_SIP_PROXY_PORT).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_SIP_PROXY_PORT, DEFAULT_SIP_PROXY_PORT));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_STUN_UDP).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_STUN_UDP, DEFAULT_STUN_UDP));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_STUN_UDP_PORT).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_STUN_UDP_PORT, DEFAULT_STUN_UDP_PORT));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_STUN_TCP).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_STUN_TCP, DEFAULT_STUN_TCP));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_STUN_TCP_PORT).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_STUN_TCP_PORT, DEFAULT_STUN_TCP_PORT));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TURN_UDP).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TURN_UDP, DEFAULT_TURN_UDP));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TURN_UDP_PORT).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TURN_UDP_PORT, DEFAULT_TURN_UDP_PORT));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TURN_TCP).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TURN_TCP, DEFAULT_TURN_TCP));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TURN_TCP_PORT).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TURN_TCP_PORT, DEFAULT_TURN_TCP_PORT));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TCP_MODE).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TCP_MODE, DEFAULT_TCP_MODE));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_AFE_MODE).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_AFE_MODE, DEFAULT_AFE_MODE));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_BWM_MODE).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_BWM_MODE, DEFAULT_BWM_MODE));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_HTTP_PROXY).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_HTTP_PROXY, DEFAULT_HTTP_PROXY));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_HTTP_PROXY_PORT).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_HTTP_PROXY_PORT, DEFAULT_HTTP_PROXY_PORT));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_HTTP_DOMAIN).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_HTTP_DOMAIN, DEFAULT_HTTP_DOMAIN));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TURN_USERNAME).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TURN_USERNAME, DEFAULT_TURN_USERNAME));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TURN_PASSWORD).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TURN_PASSWORD, DEFAULT_TURN_PASSWORD));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME, DEFAULT_HTTP_PROXY_USERNAME));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD, DEFAULT_HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_TRANSPORT_MODE).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_TRANSPORT_MODE, DEFAULT_TRANSPORT_MODE));
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_AUTO_ANSWER).setSummary(settings.getString(PREF_AUTO_ANSWER, DEFAULT_AUTO_ANSWER));
    }
```

But here the warning message is shown and sometimes I don't get any preferences set on the setting page. Can anyone say me that what is the root cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody deprecated that method using the `@Deprecated` annotation, because they believe it should no longer be used.
You should find where that method is declared and read the documentation under `@deprecated` if provided, or find whoever manages that method in your organization to find out what alternatives they are suggesting.

**Edit:** My apologies, didn't realize this is an Android snippet. See [android - getPreferenceScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416561/getpreferencescreen) question made by another user.
They are suggesting that you should use `getPreferenceManager()` instead.

Like so:

```
getPreferenceManager().findPreference("keep").setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: `getPreferenceManager()` is deprecated now too. Is there a new alternative?